# Mockito не мокает метод (Wanted but not invoked)

Tags: junit, mockito

всем привет.
Есть вот такой класс:

```
public class Class_A {


public String method1(String str1){
    try {

        return Class_B.calc(str1);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // вот здесь  e.getMessage() = "Ошибка сервиса"
        throw new MyException(e.getMessage(), e);
    }

}


public boolean method2(String str1, String str2){

    return method1(str1).equals(str2);
}


public void throwMyExceptionIfNoUser(String str1, String str2) throw MyException {
    if (!method2(st1, str2)) {
        throw new MyException(String.format("Отсутвует пользователь %s", str1));
    }
}
```

}

Есть вот такой тест:

```
    @ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
```

@RunWith(JUnitPlatform.class)
//@MockitoSettings(strictness = Strictness.LENIENT)

class Class_ATest {

```
@org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach
void setUp() {
}

@org.junit.jupiter.api.AfterEach
void tearDown() {
}


/**
 * этот тест возвращает вот это
 *
 * java.lang.NullPointerException
 * at ua.avk.junit.Class_A.method1(Class_A.java:9)
 *
 */
@org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
void throwMyExceptionIfNoUser_v1() {
    String str1 = "str1";
    String str2 = "str2";

    Class_A  classA = Mockito.spy(new Class_A());

    Assertions.assertNotNull(classA);

    Mockito.when(classA.method2(str1, str2)).thenReturn(false);
    //Mockito.doReturn(false).when(classA).method2(str1, str2);

    MyException myException = Assertions.assertThrows(
            MyException.class,
            () -> { throw new MyException(String.format("Отсутвует пользователь %s", str2)); }
    );

    //Mockito.verify(classA).hasRole(str1, str2);

    //String exp = String.format("Ошибка сервиса Отсутвует пользователь %s", str2);
    String exp = String.format("Отсутвует пользователь %s", str2);
    String act = myException.getMessage();

    Assertions.assertEquals(exp, act);
}



/**
 * этот тест возвращает вот это
 *
 *
 * Wanted but not invoked:
 * classA.method2(
 * "str1",
 * "str2"
 * );
 * -> at ua.avk.junit.Class_ATest.throwMyExceptionIfNoUser_v2(Class_ATest.java:73)
 * Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.
 *
 * Но если убрать проверку Mockito.verify то он возвращвет  "Ошибка сервисa Отсутвует пользователь %s", str2"
 * Получается что он не мокает method2
 */
@org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
void throwMyExceptionIfNoUser_v2() {
    String str1 = "str1";
    String str2 = "str2";

    Class_A  classA = Mockito.mock(Class_A.class);

    Assertions.assertNotNull(classA);

    Mockito.when(classA.method2(str1, str2)).thenReturn(false);

    MyException myException = Assertions.assertThrows(
            MyException.class,
            () -> { throw new MyException(String.format("Отсутвует пользователь %s", str2)); }
    );

    Mockito.verify(classA).hasRole(str1, str2);

    //String exp = String.format("Ошибка сервисa Отсутвует пользователь %s", str2);
    String exp = String.format("Отсутвует пользователь %s", str2);
    String act = myException.getMessage();

    Assertions.assertEquals(exp, act);

}
```

}

использую вот такие депенденси:

```
        <jupiter.version>5.7.0</jupiter.version>
    <junit-platform.version>1.7.2</junit-platform.version>
    <mockito.jupiter.version>3.7.7</mockito.jupiter.version>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
        <version>${jupiter.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
        <version>${jupiter.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
        <version>${jupiter.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-platform-runner</artifactId>
        <version>${junit-platform.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
        <version>${mockito.jupiter.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-junit-jupiter</artifactId>
        <version>${mockito.jupiter.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito2</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.9</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Результаты выполнения тестов приведены в коментах к тестам
**Получается что мокито ничего не мокает!? ПОЧЕМУ???** Или, быть может, я не правильно понимаю технологию работы моков???

Помогите пожалуйста решить проблему с моками, уже перелопатил кучу доков (на stackOverflow -> тоже), но вразумительного ответа, к сожалению, так и не нашел...
Заранее благодарен за ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка Wanted but not invoked говорит, что метод (в нашем примере - это method2), вызов которого замокан (т.е. в случае его вызова будет возвращаться определенный ожидаемый результат) НЕ был вызван. Мокание методов НЕ равно вызову методу, это описание работы метода и его результат.

```
@Test
public void throwMyExceptionIfNoUser_v2() throws MyException {
    String str1 = "str1";
    String str2 = "str2";
    Class_A class_a = new Class_A();
    
    Class_A spyClass_A = spy(class_a);
    doReturn(false).when(spyClass_A).method2(str1, str2);
    
    try {
        spyClass_A.throwMyExceptionIfNoUser(str1, str2);
    } catch (MyException e) {
        assertEquals("Отсутствует пользователь str1", e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: спаибо за быстрый ответ но мне он не помог - к сожалению
1)данный тест я делал исходя из оф доков (линки на екземпл уже нет). 2) если добавить вызов classA.throwMyExceptionIfNoUser(str1, str2); **результат - тотже**. 3) Почему он вызывает method1?. Спасибо

Comment: Приложил пример.

Comment: Спасибо. данный пример обработки исключения через try catch вероятно помог решить данный вопрос. тк
{
try {
        spyClass_A.throwMyExceptionIfNoUser(str1, str2);
**Mockitp.verify(spyClassA).method2(str1, str2) //отработал хорошо**
    } catch (MyException e) {
        assertEquals("Отсутствует пользователь str1", e.getMessage());
    }
 
}